# Is it possible to override a systemd unit file to create a template unit file?

Tags: linux, systemd

I know that systemd provides an excellent mechanism to override a package-provided unit file to influence the service configuration/behavior. This is typically done by using the below command

```
sudo systemctl edit <unitfile>
```

to create an override conf file at

```
/etc/systemd/system/<unitfile.d>/
```

Systemd also provides a separate mechanism to define a template unit file, and have it instantiated to create instance-specific units at runtime. This requires naming the template file as

```
<servicename>@.service
```

and then instantiating it as

```
systemctl start <servicename>@<instancename>
```

Now, I have a situation where I would like to run a package-provided service as multiple unit instances. I want to avoid creating my own template unit file, so I am trying to see if the package-provided unit file can be overriden to create the template unit file.

Since, per my understanding, the template unit file has a naming convention that is different from the regular unit file, I think I cannot override the package-provided unit file with a template file by placing it in /etc/systemd/system.

Is there any defined way to achieve what I am trying to do?

Specific scenario:
The grafana package installs a grafana-server.service unit file. I want to run two instances of grafana on my machine - one each for DEV and STG. I have been able to do this:

- modify the grafana-server.service file (using %I to set folder locations & file paths)
- rename the modified grafana-server.service to grafana-server@.service
- start instances of grafana by using:

  ```
  sudo systemctl start grafana-server@dev
  ```

  and

  ```
  sudo systemctl start grafana-server@stg
  ```

However, this breaks the link from the grafana provided service unit file, and if they enhance the service file when I upgrade, I will need to redo this activity again. My objective is to avoid this direct dependency, and instead convert it to an override dependency.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For both options below, first override the grafana-server.service (without the @) on `/etc/systemd/system` and suppress `ExecStart` (supposing it uses that) to make it starts nothing. On `/etc/systemd/system/grafana-server.service.d/10-disable-execstart.conf`:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
WorkingDirectory=/path/to/your/confdir
```

## Option 1 - Overriding with generic instances

Create a `grafana-server@.service` that corresponds to your settings with the following configuration to `[Unit]` and `[Service]`:

```
[Unit]
PartOf=grafana-server.service
ReloadPropagatedFrom=grafana-server.service
```

These should bind grafana-server start/stop/restart to all your instances together. The *magic* is not very well documented, but if you put `<instance_name>.conf` files on your `/path/to/your/confdir`, all those instances will be bound automagically!

## Option 2 - Overriding specific instances to keep package config

If you want to keep all *update goodness* from package service file, but accept mainaining custom instances options, create a symbolic link for each instance name from generic

```
/lib/systemd/system/grafana-server.service
```

to

```
/etc/systemd/system/grafana-service@<instance>.service
```

and then override only the specific options of that instance using

```
/etc/systemd/system/grafana-server@<instance>.service.d/99-my-options.conf
```

Make sure to add the following configuration to `[Unit]` and `[Service]` to `99-my-options.conf`:

```
[Unit]
PartOf=grafana-server.service
ReloadPropagatedFrom=grafana-server.service
```

This will assume for each instance all `grafana-server.service` options and will override them with all options on `99-my-options.conf` file and also bind start/stop/restart actions to grafana-server.service.

On both options, if you run

```
systemctl start grafana-server.service
```

all your instances which have a `/path/to/confdir/<instance>.conf` file will be started. The same apply to `stop` and `restart` AND you can always manage them individually by using their `grafana-server@<instance>` service name.