# How to specify different resource limits for different instances of a systemd instantiated service?

Tags: systemd

For reasons above my paygrade, I need to run multiple instances of a DB server on a physical host with a bare metal OS. I also need to limit the physical memory use of each instance.

I am using a template unit file to start up a few dozen instances. I am using `EnvironmentFile` to specify different environment variables and command line arguments for each instance.

However, I also want to be able to specify a different memory limit for each instance. AFAICT, environment variable substitution does not work for resource limit options like `MemoryHigh`.

I thought drop-in files would be the answer, but I couldn't a single example of using drop-in files with an instantiated service. Is there some way I can create one drop-in file for `myservice@1`, a different drop-in file for `myservice@2`, etc?

```
$ cat /etc/systemd/system/myservice@.service

[Unit]
Description=Something
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=forking    
EnvironmentFile=/etc/myservice/myservice.%i.env
ExecStart=/usr/bin/myservice $OPTIONS_FROM_ENV
MemoryHigh=4G

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: I have no idea if systemd can currently do this. I would like to see any workarounds.

Comment: I created a few separate service files with pre-defined resource limits, e.g. "myservice-large@.service", "myservice-medium@.service", "myservice-small@.service", etc.

Obviously this is painful from a management perspective, now I have to know/remember/guess which service is running which instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found what I'm looking for in this answer: https://serverfault.com/a/879705/62991

Just create a drop-in directory with the instance name, and you can override settings there just like you can for a non-instantiated service.

In the below example, instances of `myservice` have a 4GiB memory limit by default, but `myservice@1` and `myservice@2` have their own settings. Works fine with systemd 231 on Fedora 25.

```
$ cat /etc/systemd/system/myservice@.service
[Unit]
Description=Something
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=forking    
EnvironmentFile=/etc/myservice/myservice.%i.env
ExecStart=/usr/bin/myservice $OPTIONS_FROM_ENV
MemoryHigh=4G

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

$ cat /etc/systemd/system/myservice@1.service.d/99-memory.conf
[Service]
MemoryHigh=10G

$ cat /etc/systemd/system/myservice@2.service.d/99-memory.conf
[Service]
MemoryHigh=20G
```