# Why does systemd reject my unit name as 'neither a valid invocation ID nor unit name'?

Tags: systemd

I need to [override the `ExecStart` Parameter of a *systemd* template](https://serverfault.com/questions/844202/is-it-possible-to-override-a-systemd-unit-file-to-create-a-template-unit-file). I have confirmed that the unit file exists & passes validation. Adding a `unique-name@.service.d/override.conf` file works well on some machines:

```
user@prod-west-1604$ systemctl --version | head -1
systemd 229
user@prod-west-1604$ file -b /etc/systemd/system/unique-name@.service
symbolic link to /lib/systemd/system/nginx.service

user@prod-west-1604$ sudo systemctl edit unique-name@.service
# (opens editor as expected)
```

However, on machines running newer systemd versions, the operation fails:

```
user@prod-east-1810$ systemctl --version | head -1
systemd 239
user@prod-east-1810$ file -b /etc/systemd/system/unique-name@.service
symbolic link to /lib/systemd/system/nginx.service

user@prod-east-1810$ sudo systemctl edit unique-name@.service
Failed to get the load state of unique-name@.service: Unit name unique-name@.service is neither a valid invocation ID nor unit name.
```

**Why**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is caused by a [*systemd* bug introduced in v233 and fixed in v240](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/9554). It is not necessary to upgrade *systemd*, in most cases `systemctl edit` is little more than a shortcut for the following anyway:

```
sudo mkdir -p /etc/systemd/system/unique-name@.service.d/
sudo vim /etc/systemd/system/unique-name@.service.d/override.conf
```

**The override files will work, even in *systemd* versions where the `systemctl edit` command does not.** Do not forget to apply new configuration using:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

Answer (score 1):

I received the same error message about '***neither a valid invocation ID nor unit name***' when starting a service failed, but the fix was different than the accepted answer and unrelated to the bug.  The error message was a total red-herring and a time waster as I explain below.

My issue was with systemd `netfilter-persistent` service. The error message lead me to believe there was a problem with the systemd-gears starting the service.  Then I had an epiphany: What if there was a duff `iptables` rule in "***rules.v4***" the service called?

Yup: the service wasn't starting because of a dependent file required to raise it, in this case "***rules.v4***" had an error.  This didn't appear in the `systemctl status` or `journalctl -xe`. A sed expression failed to match and replace a placeholder with a subnet.  Once I the rules file built correctly, the service rose-up correctly.

**When investigating this error message, don't get so blinkered looking at the systemd service definition itself that you don't review any dependent files being called that might be in error error.**

Anyhoo, hope this saves others from chasing their tail with this error message.

Comment: Are you saying you got that exact `neither` error message for a failed `ConditionPathExists=` check? If so, please link the relevant bug in the systemd bug tracker.

Comment: No, the error message recorded in the title of this question '***neither a valid invocation ID nor unit name***'. That's the error I was speaking to.  Indeed, when I was struggling to resolve it and Googling, this question was returned in the results.